# How to create a 'sign in' code for app in android?

Tags: php, android

I want to make a login page. In my app I'm thinking of  accepting mobile number as username and a 6 digit random number as a password key which will be valid for 30 days in php table in server
-- this is the steps I thought of:

1. I will make the user click on submit button which will give the user
   a 30 sec toast displaying the random 6 digit number to put in the
   password Edit-text.
2. once that happens the user will sign into activity and then it
   closes it  (here I m confused whether to make user make note of 6
   digit number as in server the password only dies after 30 days)

hence once the application closes the user will not be able to sign in till 30 days.

***Am i approaching in right direction and have to dump the idea.***
The App is not holding any confidential content.

I'm at novice level in android and hence would be thankful if someone 
gives a sample code also.

Comment: just some thoughs, i think in general mobile apps doesn't need a password, as long as you can get their mobile number as login. since if a user is serious about security they'll most likely enable password protection for their phone. plus your app isn't some kind of banking app / stored credit card info e.t.c.

Comment: if you're concern with "how to identify unique user" instead of "security" , you can go check out the offical android site.  http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html

Answer (score 0):

To make a login for an app, a better approach would be to allow the user to enter their own password, which is sent to the php script and is hashed into a 'key' for secure storage.

That way, the password can be verified each time on the PHP side by comparing the entered password converted to the hash and comparing to the existing entry in the database.

This method obviously does not require storing any secure information on the phone itself, but also removes the need for the user to enter a unique code every 30 days. Instead, if the user attempts to login after 30 days with that code, the PHP should return an 'expired' message, and allow the user to create a new password

I'm not sure how I would supply sample code for this, because it would all depend on how you plan on posting the information to the PHP server